# Let users send message in other languages via FormtoEmail

Tags: email, unicode

If anyone's used formtoemail.com for email before, I'm trying to accept other languages. For example, I just had the following message come in. How do I fix it?

comments: http://propohudenie.com/earn/423-ot-1500-2000-rub-v-den-na-prosmotre-videorolikov-bez-vlozheniy-i-prodazh.html>ÐºÑƒÑ€Ñ  Ñƒ ÑˆÐ¸Ñ…Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð° Ð·Ð°Ñ€Ð°Ð±Ð¾Ñ‚Ð¾Ðº Ð² Ð¸Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð½ÐµÑ‚Ðµ

ÐžÑ€Ð³Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ð·Ð°Ñ†Ð¸Ñ  â€œÐŸÑ€Ð¾Ð²ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ½Ð½Ñ‹Ðµ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ñ‹ Ð¸ ÑƒÑ Ð»ÑƒÐ³Ð¸â€  Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÐ´Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚Ð°Ð²Ð»Ñ ÐµÑ‚ Ð´Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²ÐµÑ€Ð½ÑƒÑŽ Ð¸ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð²ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ½Ð½ÑƒÑŽ Ð¸Ð½Ñ„Ð¾Ñ€Ð¼Ð°Ñ†Ð¸ÑŽ Ð¾ Ð²Ñ ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ð·Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶Ð½Ñ‹Ñ… Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ð°Ñ… Ð¸ Ñ ÐµÑ€Ð²Ð¸Ñ Ð°Ñ… Ð´Ð»Ñ  Ð½Ð°Ñ ÐµÐ»ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ . Ð Ð°ÑˆÐµÐ¹ Ð·Ð°Ð´Ð°Ñ‡ÐµÐ¹ ÐµÑ Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð²ÐµÑ€ÐºÐ° ÐºÐ°Ñ‡ÐµÑ Ñ‚Ð²Ð° Ñ ÐµÑ€Ð²Ð¸Ñ Ð° Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ð°, ÐºÐ¾Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‹Ðµ Ñ€ÐµÐ°Ð»Ð¸Ð·ÑƒÑŽÑ‚Ñ Ñ  Ð² Ñ ÐµÑ‚Ð¸. ÐŸÐ¾Ñ Ð»Ðµ Ð½Ð°ÑˆÐµÐ¹ Ð¸Ð½Ñ Ð¿ÐµÐºÑ†Ð¸Ð¸ Ð½Ð° ÐºÐ°Ñ‡ÐµÑ Ñ‚Ð²Ð¾ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ñ‹ Ð¸ Ñ ÐµÑ€Ð²Ð¸Ñ Ñ‹ Ñ€Ð°Ð·Ð¼ÐµÑ‰Ð°ÑŽÑ‚Ñ Ñ  Ð² ÐºÐ°Ñ‚Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ð³Ðµ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð²ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ½Ð½Ñ‹Ñ… Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ð¾Ð² Ð¸ ÑƒÑ Ð»ÑƒÐ³. Ð”Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ ÐºÐ°Ñ‚Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ð³ Ð¿Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÑ‚ Ð»ÑŽÐ´Ñ Ð¼ Ð¿Ð¾Ð´Ð¾Ð±Ñ€Ð°Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð½ÐµÐ¾Ð±Ñ…Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ð¼Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€ Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ ÑƒÑ Ð»ÑƒÐ³Ñƒ, Ð½Ðµ Ñ Ð¾Ð¼Ð½ÐµÐ²Ð°Ñ Ñ ÑŒ Ð² Ð¸Ñ… ÐºÐ°Ñ‡ÐµÑ Ñ‚Ð²Ðµ.

http://propohudenie.com/earn/423-ot-1500-2000-rub-v-den-na-prosmotre-videorolikov-bez-vlozheniy-i-prodazh.html>Ð¾Ñ‚ 1500 Ñ€ÑƒÐ±Ð»ÐµÐ¹ Ð² Ð´ÐµÐ½ÑŒ Ð½Ð° Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ñ Ð¼Ð¾Ñ‚Ñ€Ð°Ñ… Ð²Ð¸Ð´ÐµÐ¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð»Ð¸ÐºÐ¾Ð² (Ñ ÐµÑ€Ð³ÐµÐ¹ ÑˆÐ¸Ñ…Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²)

ÐžÑ Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð½Ñ‹Ð¼Ð¸ Ð½Ð°Ð¿Ñ€Ð°Ð²Ð»ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ Ð¼Ð¸ Ð½Ð°ÑˆÐµÐ¹ Ð´ÐµÑ Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒÐ½Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚Ð¸ ÐµÑ Ñ‚ÑŒ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ñ‹ Ð¸ ÑƒÑ Ð»ÑƒÐ³Ð¸, Ñ Ð²Ñ Ð·Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ðµ Ñ  Ð¿Ð¾Ñ…ÑƒÐ´ÐµÐ½Ð¸ÐµÐ¼ Ð¸ Ð·Ð°Ñ€Ð°Ð±Ð¾Ñ‚ÐºÐ¾Ð¼ Ð² Ð˜Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð½ÐµÑ‚Ðµ. Ð­Ñ‚Ð¸ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ñ‹ Ð¸ Ñ ÐµÑ€Ð²Ð¸Ñ Ñ‹ Ñ‡Ð°Ñ‰Ðµ Ð²Ñ ÐµÐ³Ð¾ Ð¿Ð¾Ð´Ð²ÐµÑ€Ð³Ð°ÑŽÑ‚Ñ Ñ  Ñ„Ð°Ð»ÑŒÑ Ð¸Ñ„Ð¸ÐºÐ°Ñ†Ð¸Ð¸, Ð²Ñ Ð»ÐµÐ´Ñ Ñ‚Ð²Ð¸Ðµ Ð¸Ñ… ÑˆÐ¸Ñ€Ð¾ÐºÐ¾Ð¹ Ð²Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚Ñ€ÐµÐ±Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð½Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚Ð¸.

http://propohudenie.com/earn/431-ot-1300-v-mesyac-na-kulinarnyh-receptah.html>Ñ‚Ð°Ñ‚ÑŒÑ Ð½Ñ‹ Ð·Ð¾Ñ€Ð¸Ð½Ð¾Ð¹ Ð·Ð°Ñ€Ð°Ð±Ð¾Ñ‚Ð¾Ðº Ð½Ð° ÐºÑƒÐ»Ð¸Ð½Ð°Ñ€Ð½Ñ‹Ñ… Ð¸Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð½ÐµÑ‚ Ð¸Ð·Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ Ñ…

ÐœÑ‹ Ð¾Ñ ÑƒÑ‰ÐµÑ Ñ‚Ð²Ð»Ñ ÐµÐ¼ ÐºÐ²Ð°Ð»Ð¸Ñ„Ð¸Ñ†Ð¸Ñ€Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð½ÑƒÑŽ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð²ÐµÑ€ÐºÑƒ Ð½Ð° ÐºÐ°Ñ‡ÐµÑ Ñ‚Ð²Ð¾ Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ñ… ÑƒÑ Ð»ÑƒÐ³ Ð¸ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ð¾Ð², Ð¿Ð¾Ñ Ð»Ðµ Ñ‡ÐµÐ³Ð¾ Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÐ´Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚Ð°Ð²Ð»Ñ ÐµÐ¼ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ»Ñ Ð¼ Ð¸Ð½Ñ„Ð¾Ñ€Ð¼Ð°Ñ†Ð¸ÑŽ Ð¾ Ñ€ÐµÐ·ÑƒÐ»ÑŒÑ‚Ð°Ñ‚Ð°Ñ… Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð²ÐµÑ€ÐºÐ¸. ÐœÑ‹ Ñ‚Ð°ÐºÐ¶Ðµ Ñ Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÐ¼ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð½Ñ Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð¶Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ð±Ñ‹ Ð¾Ñ‚ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÐµÐ¹ Ð½Ð° ÐºÐ°ÐºÑƒÑŽ-Ð½Ð¸Ð±ÑƒÐ´ÑŒ ÑƒÑ Ð»ÑƒÐ³Ñƒ Ð»Ð¸Ð±Ð¾ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€, Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÐ´Ð»Ð°Ð³Ð°ÐµÐ¼Ñ‹Ðµ Ð² Ð˜Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð½ÐµÑ‚Ðµ, Ð½Ð° Ð½ÐµÐ´Ð¾Ð±Ñ€Ð¾Ñ Ð¾Ð²ÐµÑ Ñ‚Ð½Ð¾Ðµ Ð¾Ñ‚Ð½Ð¾ÑˆÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ñ„Ð¸Ñ€Ð¼-Ñ€ÐµÐ°Ð»Ð¸Ð·Ð°Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð². Ð Ð°Ñˆ ÐºÐ°Ñ‚Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ð³ Ð¸Ð¼ÐµÐµÑ‚ Ñ‚Ð°ÐºÐ¶Ðµ Ð¸Ð½Ñ„Ð¾Ñ€Ð¼Ð°Ñ†Ð¸ÑŽ Ð¾ ÐºÐ°Ñ‡ÐµÑ Ñ‚Ð²Ðµ Ð´Ñ€ÑƒÐ³Ð¸Ñ… Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ð¾Ð² Ð¸ ÑƒÑ Ð»ÑƒÐ³ â€“ ÐºÐ¾Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‹Ðµ Ð½Ðµ Ð¾Ñ‚Ð½Ð¾Ñ Ñ Ñ‚Ñ Ñ  Ðº ÐºÐ°Ñ‚ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ñ€Ð¸Ñ Ð¼ Ð·Ð°Ñ€Ð°Ð±Ð¾Ñ‚ÐºÐ° Ð² Ñ ÐµÑ‚Ð¸ Ð¸ Ð¿Ð¾Ñ…ÑƒÐ´ÐµÐ½Ð¸ÑŽ, Ð¼Ñ‹ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð²ÐµÑ€Ñ ÐµÐ¼ ÐºÐ°Ñ‡ÐµÑ Ñ‚Ð²Ð¾ Ð»ÑŽÐ±Ñ‹Ñ… ÑƒÑ Ð»ÑƒÐ³ Ð¸ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ð¾Ð².

submit: Send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure the form at the formtoemail.com control panel to accept content in the same encoding you're using to serve your HTML page containing the `<form>`.

UTF-8 is the sensible choice for this as it allows all characters, but unfortunately the default is ISO-8859-1 and the free version of the service doesn't let you change it.

It's possible to rescue the text above by encoding it to ISO-8859-1 bytes and then decoding it to test using UTF-8. But that's a right pain to do for every mail that comes in. For what it's worth, the above appears to have come from spambot anyway so you're not missing much.

I would look for a different form sending service.